# Delete row from table and sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, tableview

I still need your help.
I have this piece of code that doesn't want to work.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    NSDictionary *rowVals = (NSDictionary *) [shoppingListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *keyValue = (NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"key"];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    sqlite3 *db;
    int dbrc; //Codice di ritorno del database (database return code)
    DatabaseShoppingListAppDelegate *appDelegate = (DatabaseShoppingListAppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    const char *dbFilePathUTF8 = [appDelegate.dbFilePath UTF8String];
    dbrc = sqlite3_open(dbFilePathUTF8, &db);
    if (dbrc) {
        NSLog(@"Impossibile aprire il Database!");
        return;
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *dbps; //Istruzione di preparazione del database

    NSString *deleteStatementsNS = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM \"shoppinglist\" WHERE key='%@'", keyValue];
    const char *deleteStatement = [deleteStatementsNS UTF8String];
    dbrc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteStatement, -1, &dbps, NULL);
    dbrc = sqlite3_step(dbps);


    //faccio pulizia rilasciando i database
    sqlite3_finalize(dbps);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [shoppingListItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadData];

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
}
```

Actually, it's working fine. I can swipe to a row in the table, delete it, i have my fade effect, the content is removed from the database and from the table.
But if I try to remove another element just after the first one I have a SIGABRT on

```
    [shoppingListItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

If I move to another tab, go back and remove a row, everything works fine... 
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my mac... sometimes this code works, sometimes don't... And there is a problem with the last row too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope shoppingListItems array contains Dictinaries . so have that Object In Array u can Directly Delete that particular object From Array.
TRY LIKE THIS.....

```
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    NSDictionary *rowVals = (NSDictionary *) [shoppingListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *keyValue = (NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"key"];
    sqlite3 *db;
    int dbrc; //Codice di ritorno del database (database return code)
    DatabaseShoppingListAppDelegate *appDelegate = (DatabaseShoppingListAppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    const char *dbFilePathUTF8 = [appDelegate.dbFilePath UTF8String];
    dbrc = sqlite3_open(dbFilePathUTF8, &db);
    if (dbrc) {
        NSLog(@"Impossibile aprire il Database!");
        return;
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *dbps; //Istruzione di preparazione del database

    NSString *deleteStatementsNS = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM \"shoppinglist\" WHERE key='%@'", keyValue];
    const char *deleteStatement = [deleteStatementsNS UTF8String];
    dbrc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteStatement, -1, &dbps, NULL);
    dbrc = sqlite3_step(dbps);


    //faccio pulizia rilasciando i database
    sqlite3_finalize(dbps);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    [shoppingListItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [tableView reloadData];
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, i have Dictionaries in there. I did as you wrote. I tried and it worked... just once (lol). Now i have this "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on the same row.

Comment: Why are you working without `[tableView beginUpdates];` & `[tableView endUpdates];` ? Does it work anyway? I can't see any other differences...

Comment: Well... i think your answer is the most significative here XD I'll try it asap.

Comment: well... it doesn't start at all eheh

Answer (score 1):

You might want to swap around

> ```
> [tableView reloadData];
> [tableView endUpdates];
> ```

to make it

> ```
> [tableView endUpdates];
> [tableView reloadData];
> ```

Alternatively please tell us what the error message for the SIGABRT is.

Comment: Ok I fixed this, I wrote i wrong for some reason maybe while i was trying to do something... but that was not the problem. As i wrote to Srinivas now i have another problem...