# Deleting row from table view and record from sqlite database

Tags: ios, uitableview, sqlite, sql-delete

I have created an sqlite table using the following statement:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reminders (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Name VARCHAR(64), Event VARCHAR(64), Date VARCHAR(64), Bfr VARCHAR(64), Val VARCHAR(64),Num VARCHAR(64), Bod VARCHAR(400) ,Grp VARCHAR(64))";
```

I have successfully inserted data and retrieved data from sqlite database and displayed the reminders in view reminders too programmatically!

But I am struck with deletion of records from sqlite database.I mean I have used a model class to hold the values like name,event,date etc...In add reminder page,I have assigned the values for the variables declared in the model class,i.e.

textField.text = remClass.Name etc..

My description might sound confusing,but the above information is always useful to answer this question with ease.

I have add reminder page,where user enters data and clicks save,then data gets inserted in to database.There is View Reminders page where the user can view the saved reminder.In that there are 3 different ways to view reminders:viewAll,viewMonthly,viewGroup.Now in view all I was able to display the unique ID for every reminder using the following statement:

```
ReminderClass *loadedReminder = [[ReminderClass alloc] init];

loadedReminder.reminderID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
```

Where reminder class is a model class which holds all the values entered in add reminder page.

In order to display the saved reminder,I have used an array and added the model class object after retrieving every row,i.e. id,name,event,date etc.. and populated the table view accordingly.Say if i save 3 reminders,then sections are 3 like wise and so on...

Now if I click the edit button in view group reminders page,then as we know we can delete the row(section) of table view by clicking the orientation button on left.

If I delete the row,say a row with reminder.Then the data corresponding to that reminder should also be deleted from sqlite database.

How can I do this,I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306309/delete-row-from-table-and-sqlite-database) sounds similar to my requirement.But its not working.

Finally I have implemented the following code for deletion:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {        
        [self.grpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &remindersDB)==SQLITE_OK)
        {   
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledstatement;

            int pk = sqlite3_column_int(compiledstatement, 0);
            NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from reminders where ID = %i",pk];

            const char *sqlstmt=[querySQL UTF8String];

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(remindersDB, sqlstmt, -1, &compiledstatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
            {                
                if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledstatement))

                    NSAssert1(0,@"Error while creating delete statement => %s",sqlite3_errmsg(remindersDB));
            }
            NSLog(@"delete DONE");
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledstatement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(remindersDB);

        [self.gTable reloadData];
    }
```

**RETRIEVAL CODE:**

```
-(void)loadgReminders
{

    EventsReminderAppDelegate *appDelegate = (EventsReminderAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSLog(@"String = %@",appDelegate.groupString);

    self.grpArray = nil;
    self.grpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //Retrieve the group of reminder
    const char *thePath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statment;

    if (sqlite3_open(thePath, &remindersDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *getQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM reminders WHERE Grp = '%@' ORDER BY Date ASC",appDelegate.groupString];
        const char *sqlite_stmt = [getQuery UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.remindersDB, sqlite_stmt, -1, &statment, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                ReminderClass *remind = [[ReminderClass alloc]init];
                remind.reminderID = sqlite3_column_int(statment, 0);
                **NSLog(@"reminderID=%d",remind.reminderID);**
                remind.Name = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 1)];
                remind.Event = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 2)];
                remind.Date = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 3)];
                remind.numDays = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 4)];
                remind.selString = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 5)];
                remind.number = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 6)];
                remind.msgBody = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 7)];
                remind.remGroup = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 8)];

                NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
                NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:remind.Date];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
                NSString *dateVal = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
                remind.Date = dateVal;

                [self.grpArray addObject:remind];

                [remind release];
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statment);
        }

        sqlite3_close(remindersDB);
    }
}
```

There I used NSLog for checking whether reminder ID values are getting displayed properly or not it is getting displayed as:

[image]

But what's wrong when I try to do the same with deletion to retrieve the id values and assign that id value to where id=?.

It's not working, where am I wrong?

Can any one please help me out?

Comment: @Jennis Thanks for the concern...Actually row as well as record is not getting deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this. This will definitely work out

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
        {

            NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];

            NSString *couponIdValue = [listOfCouponId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

                const char *sql = "delete from reminders where ID = ?";
                sqlite3_stmt *deletestmt;
                if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deletestmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
                    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }



                sqlite3_bind_int(deletestmt, 1, [IdValue intValue]);


                if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deletestmt)) 
                    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


                sqlite3_reset(deletestmt);

}
```

pass the value of id in sqlite3_bind_int() method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but what is that IdValue

Comment: id value is the value for which you want to delete data

Comment: Can you place the code sample for the id value also please,thanks in advance :)

Comment: How to retrieve that value,please help me

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6983/iphone  let's we discuss your problem at this room

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

After reading comments it seems like you're having issues aligning your in memory reminder (id) with the id in the database to delete.  The array index does not necessarily correspond.  When you create your reminder with the insert statement you have to immediately follow that call with a call to sqlite3_last_insert_rowid since it's generated.  Then assign you model classes reminderId to it.  Then in delete, simply read the reminderId to compose your delete statement.  Once again, please log everything.

http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_last_insert_rowid

After inserts, if you selected the list of reminders, ensure you're selecting the id column and assigning to the model reminderId so you know what to delete.  In both the insert and select case, you need to ensure you end up the models reminderId equal to the generated id from the db.

INITIAL:

From the code it looks like you are using a compiled statement (which is good) which means you call prepare and save the compiled statement to re-use.  If you are re-using (can't see all the code), ensure you call sqlite3_reset on it.  Also, if you are re-using, you shouldn't finalize it until you're completely done with it.

If that's not the problem, Start with logging out the pk and the composed sql statement.  make sure it's what you expect.  For example, if it's 0 and you say delete where pk = 0, then it won't fail - it just won't do anything because there is no row with an id of 0 (starts at 1).

After that, try that same statement from the sqlite3 command line.  You can log out the path that the simulator is using.

Also, log out the return code (just don't check SQLITE_DONE.  That in addition to the error message my provide a hint.

Hope one of those point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the response and answer,will make a try at it and get back to you :)

Comment: Yeah,pk value is getting displayed as null,and I have reordered sqlite3_finalize(compiledstatement) after the loop and before i close the database

Comment: Let me make you more clear with issue I am facing:I have add reminder page where user enters data and clicks save,then the reminder gets saved.I took a model class called Reminder Class for holding name,event,date etc.. values of reminder.

Comment: I have retrieved all the values of a reminder and assigned to the instance of model class variables say reminder.Name = sqlite3_column_text(statement,1) etc...

Comment: Now I did all this stuff in a method say -(void)loadReminders and added all the reminders to the array.Simply populated the table view with that array count.In view will appear simply called [self loadReminders]

Comment: So,If I add 3 reminders I get 3 cells with that corresponding reminders.When added another it becomes 4 and so on...

Comment: Hence we are ready with the reminders now,when I click delete,the row gets deleted and the corresponding record must be deleted.Please help me out,thanks for the patience in reading my elaborated comments here and concern in fixing my issue,thanks in advance :)

Comment: I edited with what i believe may be your issue based on your comments.

Comment: I understood what you said Mr.Bryanmac.I did what you said i.e. assigning rowID =  sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(remindersDB); then assigning that rowID to id declared in reminder class
reminderInstance.reminderID = rowID;
 and logged,nothing is working right for me,please help me :)

Comment: Also - just to make sure - you're putting the reminder model objects in the array and not the cells right?

Comment: Please see the Edited part of my question(post) with title RETRIEVAL CODE,which can be easy for you to understand,thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yeah sorry I have found out what's wrong,Thanks you very much