# Edit SQLite database record

Tags: android

How can I edit a particular record in a SQLite table given, `Database Name`, `Table Name`, `int _id` ,`Column Name` and `Desired value of record`?

EDIT:
My solution was `database.update(DataBaseHelper.VFS_DATABASE_TABLE, values, "_id=?", new String[] {id+""});`

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306309/delete-row-from-table-and-sqlite-database

Comment: @DmitrySavy I'm not familiar with c. Thanks.

Comment: I used `database.update(DataBaseHelper.VFS_DATABASE_TABLE, values, "_id=?", new String[] {id+""});`. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int deleteCpShadowEntryById (int id) {
    int delRows = mDb.delete(<your_table_name>, "_id" + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
    return delRows;
}
```

But I guess you do not want to delete. You want to update your value. So in this case you should at first select your row, fill the values of this row into a new ContentValues, replace you old value with new and update the row.

**Edit:** Maybe try this:

```
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put(<your_columnName>, newValue);
db.update(<your_table_name>, args, "_id" + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
```

Comment: I'm trying `public void renameVS(String name, int id) {ContentValues values = new ContentValues();values.put(DataBaseHelper.VIRTUAL_SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME, name);database.update(DataBaseHelper.VFS_DATABASE_TABLE, values, whereClause, whereArgs);}` What to put in `whereClause` and `whereArgs`?

Comment: No, you should make a query to the database, get all fields, put this fields into contentValues and then update your row.

Comment: I've updated my answer. But you should check it - i don't know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Should be a simple bit of SQL:

```
DELETE FROM <table name> WHERE <column name> = <desired value>
```

Answer (score 2):

SQLiteDatabase has a delete method :

public int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

If you have id of the particular record the code would be something like :

```
 String whereArgs[] = new String { id };
 db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id = ?", whereArgs);
```